# Embedded Struct or Nested Struct?

Tags: go, struct

Is the following code is an example of Embedded Struct or Nested Struct or something else? And  Are we using one struct type (person) in another type struct (secretAgent) ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
    first string
    last  string
    age   int
}

type secretAgent struct {
    person
    ltk bool
}

func main() {

    sa1 := secretAgent{
        person: person{
            first: "James",
            last:  "Bond",
            age:   32,
        },
        ltk: true,
    }

    fmt.Println(sa1.first, sa1.last, sa1.age, sa1.ltk)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) refers to that as an *embedded field*:

> A field declared with a type but no explicit field name is called an *embedded field*. [...]
>
> ```
> struct {
>     T1        // field name is T1
>     ...
> }
> ```

I'm not sure what you mean by "using one struct type in another struct type" but you are using `person` inside `secretAgent` by embedding one struct type inside another. The `person` fields are also promoted to behave like members of `secretAgent` in most cases:

> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

So you can say:

```
sa1 := secretAgent{
    person: person{
        first: "James",
        last:  "Bond",
        age:   32,
    },
    ltk: true,
}
```

and

```
sa1.first
```

but not:

```
sa1 := secretAgent{
    first: "James",
    last:  "Bond",
    age:   32,
    ltk: true,
}
```

You can also explicitly refer to the embedded `person` fields through the `person`:

```
// As a promoted field...
sa1.first
// More explicitly...
sa1.person.first
```

Answer (score 0):

It is both embedded and nested struct. And you can the naming convention should follow the first word should be upper case.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Name struct{
    first string
    last  string
}

type Person struct {
    name  Name  
    age   int
}

type SecretAgent struct {
    person Person
    ltk bool
}

func main() {

    sa1 := secretAgent{
        person: Person{
            name: Name {
               first: "James",
               last:  "Bond"
            },
            age:   32,
        },
        ltk: true,
    }

    fmt.Println(sa1.person.first, sa1.person.last, sa1.person.age, sa1.ltk)
}
```